# declining numerals in Old English

Tags: numerals, declension, old-english

Disclaimer : this thread is perhaps off-topic. I thank you for your indulgence since I couldn't ask such a question on https://english.stackexchange.com/ .

---

I read in the [Anglo-Saxon Chronicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon_Chronicle), [in the famous extract](http://www.oldenglishaerobics.net/anthology.html) about [Cynewulf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynewulf_of_Wessex) and Cyneheard (year 755) :

> [...] Ond se Cynewulf oft miċlum ġefeohtum feaht uuiþ Bretwālum, ond ymb
> .xxxi. wintra þæs þe hē rīċe hæfde hē wolde ādrǣfan ānne æþeling [...]
>
> (my translation)
> And Cynewulf fought great fights with the British and after 31 winters within which he had the kingdom he wanted to exile a nobleman [...]

**My question : how was "ymb .xxxi. wintra" expressed ?**

".xxxi. wintra" being a masculine genitive plural (ymb + genitive), what's the masculine genitive plural of "ān and þrītiġ" (=31) ?

**My guess : ānum and þrītiġ**

- In the *Guide To Old English* (Mitchell & Robinson; sixth edition) I read (§ 83) that "declined strong, *ān* means 'one'; when declined weak *āna*, it usually means 'alone'. So, I guess that *ān* will follow the strong declension. But what's the genitive plural of such a form ? Is it **ānum**, as expected if I follow the usual declension of the strong adjectives  ?
- In the *Guide To Old English* (Mitchell & Robinson; sixth edition) I read (§ 194) that "the cardinal numbers can be used as adjectives agreeing with a noun, e.g. [...] *mid XXXgum cyningum* 'with thirty kings'." Since ".xxxi." isn't followed by any ending, I assume that ***þrītiġ* is the expected word** (not þrītigum). Is it correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from *An Introduction to Old English* by George Leslie Brook, page 51:

> §132 The cardinal numerals from 4 to 19 generally remain uninflected when they stand before a noun; when they follow a noun and when they are used as nouns they are declined like the plurals of nouns of the i-declension; nom. and acc. m. and f. **-e**, n. **-u**; gen. **-a**, dat. **-um**.
>
> §133 The ending **-tig** of the numerals from 20 to 120 was originally a noun; the Old English numerals in **-tig** could be used either as nouns or as adjectives. When they are used as nouns the genitive ends in **-es**; when used as adjectives they are either uninflected or declined like **manig**. Since they were originally nouns, numerals in **-tig**, like **hund** and **þūsend**, may be followed by a noun in the partitive genitive. Examples are **fiftiges elna lang**, *fifty ells long*; **twentig scēapa**, *twenty sheep*. **Hund**, *hundred*, is generally uninflected, but it occasionally has dative forms in **-e**, **-um**. **þūsend**, *thousand*, is sometimes uninflected but is more often declined as a neuter noun.

According to the above quoted rules, the numeral in *ymb .xxxi. wintra* would most often remain uninflected, but it could also be declined like *manig*, many, that is like the strong adjectives. As *ān*, one is part of the number thirty-one it also would not be declined separately. So, I think the correct and most usual pronunciation of *ymb .xxxi. wintra* would be *ymb an and þrittig wintra*.